# MSBuild not recognizing assembly version in SharedAssemblyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild

I have a solution with multiple projects and created a SharedAssemblyInfo (as links) so that I can share the version number across all the projects.  I also have an AssemblyInfo file in each project for the assemblyName and guid.  When I build and run locally it runs fine.  When I attempt to build, MSBuild throws an exception when it tried to retrieve the version number.  I'm getting a null reference exception when I tried to retrieve the assembly version.  Any ideas?

Comment: give more details. It is not clear what is the difference between these two bulld attempts. Also specific exception statck trace would be helpful

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the csproj file, the file layout on disk and how you invoked msbuild to build your project. long shot: does the csproj reference the shared file via `$(SolutionDir)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the error.  In tfs, where I create a new build definition, you can specify a build template.  We are using our own custom build template, which I don't have access to see what its doing but I'm able to use it.  In the process section there was a line called "Increment version number".  This was by default selected as true.  When I set this to false I can get it to build now.  I assume our custom build template must be specifying this action to use the assemblyinfo.cs file.  So I could modify our build template to look for version number in sharedassemblyinfo.cs or in my case I just marked it not to increment version number.